# Create equidistant points along (Poly)line in R

Tags: r

If I have a Spatial Lines object like this:

```
require(sp)

x <- c(18.25721, 18.25763,18.25808,18.25846,18.25864,18.25886,18.25892,18.25913,18.25940,18.25962,
       18.25976,18.25997,18.26021,18.26048,18.26061,18.26086,18.26107,18.26128,18.26154,18.26219,
       18.26276,18.26350,18.26445,18.26510,18.26584,18.26668,18.26704,18.26807,18.26850,18.26944,
       18.27020,18.27080,18.27111,18.27134,18.27168,18.27191,18.27217,18.27254,18.27309,18.27345,
       18.27368,18.27389,18.27398,18.27400,18.27392,18.27383,18.27370) 

y <- c(44.69540,44.69539,44.69544,44.69552,44.69563,44.69586,44.69608,44.69644,44.69672,44.69687
       ,44.69701,44.69718,44.69737,44.69763,44.69771,44.69778,44.69781,44.69781,44.69782,44.69776
       ,44.69772,44.69778,44.69794,44.69805,44.69814,44.69822,44.69824,44.69826,44.69821,44.69805
       ,44.69775,44.69737,44.69728,44.69717,44.69701,44.69687,44.69671,44.69649,44.69616,44.69598
       ,44.69578,44.69560,44.69539,44.69513,44.69490,44.69476,44.69453)

river<-SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(cbind(x,y)), ID="a")))
proj4string(river) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
```

How is it possible to create points along this line every 3m for example. The result would look something like this:
[image]

I cant figure it out or find a package that just does that.

Comment: That's what interpolation functinos are for.  Or are you asking how to plot symbols, and how to plot rotated text?  If the latter, please clarify, as I have some code somewhere that'll do that sort of stuff.

Comment: Sorry I wasn`t clear enough. I want to calculate those x/y coordinates.

Comment: Well, do you know how to calculate the distance between points, or do a line integral?

Comment: Well I'm quite new to this kind of stuff but I think I know how to calculate the distance between points but I don't know anything about line integrals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't know of any library but you can achieve the result this way:

```
norm_vec <- function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2))
new_point <- function(p0, p1, di) { # Finds point in distance di from point p0 in direction of point p1
    v = p1 - p0
    u = v / norm_vec(v)
    return (p0 + u * di)
}

find <- function(river, M) {

  result = river[1,,drop=FALSE] 
  # for all subsequent points p1, p2 in this data.frame norm_vec(p2 - p1) = M at all times
  equidistantPoints = river[1,,drop=FALSE] 
  river = tail(river, n = -1)
  accDist = 0


  while (length(river) > 0) {
    point = river[1,]
    lastPoint = result[1,]

    dist = norm_vec(point - lastPoint)    

    if ( accDist + dist > M ) {
      np = new_point(lastPoint, point, M - accDist)
      equidistantPoints = rbind(np, equidistantPoints) # add np to equidistantPoints
      result = rbind(np, result) # add np to result
      accDist = 0 # reset accDist
    } else {
      #move point from river to result  
      river = tail(river, n = -1)
      result = rbind(point, result)    
      #update accDist  
      accDist = accDist + dist
    }
  }
  allPoints = result[NROW(result):1,] # reverse result
  return(list(newPoints = equidistantPoints, allPoints = allPoints))
}
```

See it plotted:

```
r = cbind(x,y) 
result = f(r, 0.003)
plot(result$allPoints, type="l", col="red", asp = 1)
points(result$allPoints, col="red")
points(result$newPoints, col="cyan")
```

[image]

The basic idea is that we keep moving along the river and calculate distance from last "checkpoint" when we realise that the `accDist + dist > M` then it means that between `lastPoint` and `point` a new point `np` must be created such that `accDist + dist_to_new_point = M`. We add this point to result and moving along the river.

Comment: This code seems to work, Thanks! Would it be possible explaining it (the idea behind it) roughly? I'm trying to get an understanding but I'm not getting the idea.

Answer (score 21):

what about the spsample() function from [sp package](https://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/sp/html/spsample.html) ? You will just sample n points, where

```
numOfPoints  <-  gLength(river) / 3
spsample(river, n = numOfPoints, type = "regular")
```

(gLength is function from [rgeos package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgeos/index.html))

Attribute **n** does not have to be an integer, so you should get pretty close estimation.

Comment: I quite like this answer a bit more than the previous one because it's a bit more straight-forward. Could the question's author change the accepted answer to this one instead?